# When I make a post, a php file is in my locale, in the console it shows me html content and in the network I get a status of 200, what's going on?

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I want that when executing the function I receive the message in the console and it does not show me that html content

```js
    function postWithFetch() {
      // URL y parámetros
      const url = 'stickerFirma.php';
            const params = new URLSearchParams();
            params.append('sesid', MySchedId);

            // Realizar petición con fetch
            fetch(url, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },
                    body: params.toString() // Convertir los parámetros a una cadena de texto
                })
                .then(response => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
                    }
                    return response.text();
                })
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error("Hubo un error en la petición:", error.message);
                });
        }
```

Comment: What is going on? It all sounds OK to me. What were you expecting to happen instead?

Comment: If your *stickerFirma.php* returns HTML with *console.log* you get HTML

Comment: It should not return html, because I am only sending a parameter, so that the stickerFirma.php obtains them and can make a query in the database

Comment: Well we don't know what your php code does, because you didn't show us. So how can we tell you if there is a problem with it? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Are you using Laravel or some other framework?